Elasticsearch SLM : Keep backups for the last <N> days. If there is more than one backup for a single day, only the latest is kept
We are taking elasticsearch backup using SLM policy which takes backup on hourly basis. With this we have retention period setup for 45 days. Now in a day it takes 24 backup which multiplies by number of days(45) for retention.
To further optimize this what we are looking at is, is there a way to keep only the latest backup for that day and delete rest of them. e.g : out of 24 backup for the day delete 23 and keep the last one.
Looking if this is possible in SLM or is there a way to achieve it.
